# Title beside a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a windows form application using visual c#. I'm wondering how should I add title text beside a textbox? For example, Commonly seen "Comments:" serves as a title for the textbox to the right of it, letting people know that comments should be entered here.

Comment: Just add a label and give the text as Comments.

Comment: There are already answers for this: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487104/how-do-i-implement-a-textbox-that-displays-type-here), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497130/watermark-for-textbox)

Comment: @tomab sry but i have to tell you, he isn't looking for watermark it is much simpler

Answer (score 5):

you can use a `Label` control, change the text and put it where ever you want.

Comment: I.e. TextBox does not have a title property. One must use a separate GUI component.