# Combobox hint text

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make a combobox with hint text `"Pick a Value"` and when start typing the value to be cleared and when its null to change the Combobox's text to Pick Value

#### In Form Load

```
comboBox1.Text = "Pick a Value";
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

The problem here is that the cusrsor position doesnt work. It selects all my text

#### In TextChanged

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (comboBox1.Text.Length == 0)
   {
      comboBox1.Text = "Pick a Value";
   }
}
```

I need this code be working only if user clears the Combobox with backspase not if i will use `ComboBox.Text = ""` in mouse click;

#### example

```
private void comboBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   //This conflicts the comboBox1_TextChanged event
   comboBox1.Text = "";
}
```

And in the end i need a code to clearing text if user start typing.

Comment: google c# watermark

Comment: You are probably looking for `CueBanner`. Not sure because `I need....I need..I need` is not a question

Comment: Rename i need to how can i make

Comment: So when the user clicks on the  combo box, you want it to clear the text?

Comment: Yes if it is possible!

Comment: Winforms Edited

Comment: Target Google to find `CueBanner` posts - its built into windows

Comment: If you use `null` instead of `""` it will work. if `comboBox1.Text == null`/`comboBox1.Text = null`

Answer (score 0):

You can you the isNullOrWhiteSpace on the TextChanged event

Something like this

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(combobox.Text))
{
      combobox.Text = "Pick a value";
}
```

But if you wanna get the desired efect, you should play with font color and opacity,or something like a watermark.

Link for watermark : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613590(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, this could help : [Watermark for Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497130/watermark-for-textbox/18497365#18497365)